# How to compare two Gini results?

Tags: gini

I'm comparing two Gini results from two distributions of income, in which one income is a source of the other. Let, say that Gini_1 = 0,770 and Gini_2 = 0,373. Clearly, Gini_2 shows a less inequal income distribution than Gini_1. However, what more can we say about that? I'm expecting to find an answer such as this one:

> What does an increase of 5 Gini points mean substantively? In a two-person cake sharing game, an increase of 5 Gini points means that the person receiving the smaller slice at t would receive two and a half percent less cake at t+1.

This was paraphrased from:

- Subramanian, S. 2002. “An Elementary Interpretation of the Gini Inequality Index.” *Theory and Decision, 52*: 375–379.

(Does anyone have a digital copy of this reference?)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to compare two Gini coefficients? This could be done with a bootstrapped confidence interval of the difference. Or you simply want to know how to interpret the difference between the two Gini coefficients?

Comment: Probably you are interested in this paper [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cjs.11275/full) with title "Jackknife empirical likelihood for comparing two Gini indices"

Comment: Thank you both @Joe_74 and @lzstat! The methods and the paper you suggested to me have answered my question.